# Python- Taking away brackets from the function call?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I'm writing a function that takes 1 argument, and I want the argument to be a list. 
I've gotten basically all of the behavior I've wanted except or ONE thing:`

```
def index_responses(a):
    j = {}
    count = 0
    key = 0
    for y in a:
       j["Q",key]=a[count]
       count+=1
       key+=1
    print(j)
    return a
```

These are the function calls:

```
print(index_responses(['a', 'b', 'c']))
print(index_responses(['d','d','b','e','e','e','d','a']))
```

And my output is this:

```
{('Q', 0): 'a', ('Q', 1): 'b', ('Q', 2): 'c'}
{('Q', 0): 'd', ('Q', 1): 'd', ('Q', 2): 'b', ('Q', 3): 'e', ('Q', 4): 'e', ('Q', 5): 'e', ('Q', 6): 'd', ('Q', 7): 'a'}
```

But I need my output to look cleaner, more like:
{( Q1: 'a', Q2: 'b' (etc...)

How do I go about cleaning up the output?

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: `j["Q"+key]=a[count]`? Change the comma to a `+` to concatenate the strings.

Comment: `{( Q1: 'a', Q2: 'b')}` is invalid syntax since `:` is used in dictionaries but in your case wrapped in a parenthesis. Can you elaborate or amend your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"Q" + str(key)` or `f"Q{str(key)}"` (on Python 3.6+) in loop:

```
def index_responses(a):
    j = {}
    count = 0
    key = 1
    for y in a:
       j["Q" + str(key)] = a[count]
       count += 1
       key += 1
    return j

print(index_responses(['a', 'b', 'c']))
print(index_responses(['d','d','b','e','e','e','d','a']))
```

Also note that you need to return `j` and not `a` which is actually the input to the function.

---

A cleaner and more pythonic way of obtaining the same result would be using a dictionary-comprehension:

```
def index_responses(a):
    return {f'Q{str(i)}': x for i, x in enumerate(a, 1)}

print(index_responses(['a', 'b', 'c']))
print(index_responses(['d','d','b','e','e','e','d','a']))

# {'Q1': 'a', 'Q2': 'b', 'Q3': 'c'}
# {'Q1': 'd', 'Q2': 'd', 'Q3': 'b', 'Q4': 'e', 'Q5': 'e', 'Q6': 'e', 'Q7': 'd', 'Q8': 'a'}
```

Comment: Would it not be simpler to start with `key=1` in this case?

Comment: @Idlehands, sure missed that.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that you want to simply concatenate 'Q' to the string representation of `key`:

```
   j["Q" + str(key)]=a[count]
```

This change gives the output

```
{'Q0': 'a', 'Q1': 'b', 'Q2': 'c'}
['a', 'b', 'c']
{'Q0': 'd', 'Q5': 'e', 'Q6': 'd', 'Q7': 'a', 'Q1': 'd', 'Q3': 'e', 'Q4': 'e', 'Q2': 'b'}
['d', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'd', 'a']
```

There are better ways to count items in a list; I'll leave those to your research.